# Multivariable Local Maximum and Minimum

Tags: calculus

Find the local maximum and minimum values and saddle point(s) of the function. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)

$$f(x, y) = 3x^3 − 9x + 9xy^2$$

I was able to solve the saddle points. $$(x,y,f)= (0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0)$$

However, I solved the local max at $(-1, 0)$ and the local min at $(1, 0)$.

I put these two values into WebAssign and it said they were incorrect. Wondering if maybe I put the values in wrong. I looked it up and asked around and I keep getting the values that I solved each time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks:)

Comment: This site asks users to report what they did. In your case how did you obtain those values.

Comment: Why do you want me to enter my answers as a comma-separated list? That's weird.